# run docker after setup network

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker. Now I encounter some problems, can anyone help me?

I want to run a container with macvlan. 
In my case, I will run a container with `--net=none` first. 
Then configure the network using ip command (or using netns in python).
the order is :

1. run a container
2. run app inside container
3. setup network

my question is that how to setup the network first. 
Then run the app. 
the order is :

1. run a container
2. setup network
3. run app inside docker

Maybe I can write network configuration script on a file and run it before the other stuff on Dockerfile. But in this way,  the network and container are highly coupling,  and I need edit it for every container everytime manually.

So is there a better way to handle this situation?
thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is the `--net=container` argument to `docker run` which shares the network namespace of the container with another container.

So you could first launch a container with `--net=none` and a script to set up the networking, then launch your application container with `--net=network_container` to use that networking stack. That would keep the network configuration and application uncoupled.

Also, take a look at the [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) project if you haven't already.

In general though, I would suggest you are better off looking at existing solutions like [Weave](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave) and [Project Calico](http://www.projectcalico.org/).